# How can I set user-level security from VBA on a different opened database?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a frontend Microsoft Access .mde database that connects to two backends simultaneously.  I also give the user the option to link to a sandbox mode backend that resides on their local computer.  While I'm developing the frontend, I stay linked to my local version of the sandbox so that I don't mess with the two backends.  Sometimes, I want to reset my sandbox to match the data in the backends.  The sandbox is a little different in that I combine the two backends together into one.  (One of the backends is just log data, so I delete that data after it's in my new sandbox.)  I have the process of copying the files and data fairly automated through VBA.

I want to also automate setting the permissions on the new sandbox file after it is copied.  The sandbox file should have much more lenient permissions since its data really doesn't matter.  I keep getting the error "Object not set." after trying to obtain the `Tables` collection in VBA in the sandbox file from my developer frontend.  I have deduced that I am able to see the `Container`s and corresponding `Document`s in the frontend developer file, but I am not able to see them from the frontend developer file when I try to access them programmatically.

I'm assuming that this must be some built-in security feature of Access.  Perhaps Microsoft doesn't want to allow a file to modify the security of a different file.  Here is some of my code to help you see what I'm doing.

All of these databases utilize the same user-level security .mdw file residing on the server.  The database was originally created in Access 2000, but I have since upgraded to Access 2010.  However, the I maintain the original Access 2000 file format to be able to utilize the built-in multi-user security.

```
Public Function CorrectSandbox()
    Dim appBackend As Application
    Dim appLog As Application
    Dim appSandbox As Application
    Dim tdf As TableDef
    Dim i As Long
    Dim doc As DAO.Document
    Dim ctr As DAO.Container

    'copy the files
    mFile.DeleteFile LOCAL_SANDBOX_PATH
    mFile.CopyFile PRODUCTION_PATH, LOCAL_SANDBOX_PATH

    'copy the log tables
    Set appSandbox = OpenSandbox()
    Set appLog = OpenLog()

    For Each tdf In appLog.CurrentDb().TableDefs
        If Left$(tdf.Name, 1) = "_" Then
            appSandbox.DoCmd.TransferDatabase acImport, "Microsoft Access", GetAdminPath(eLive), acTable, tdf.Name, tdf.Name, True
            'Set permissions for the object accordingly
            Set ctr = appSandbox.CurrentDb().Containers!Tables 
            Set doc = ctr.Documents(tdf.Name)  '*** ERROR: Object not set
            doc.UserName = "User"
            doc.Permissions = 852222
        End If
    Next tdf

    appLog.Quit
    appSandbox.Quit
End Function
```

Comment: Which version are you using?  Access did away with User Level Security in 2007, I think.

Comment: It is true that Microsoft did away with User Level Security in the 2007 accdb file format and that you cannot create a new user level security database in Access 2007 or newer.  However, we still have access to user level security on mdb files through the interface and VBA.  And to answer your question, I'm using Access 2010.